# gcc Linker and OGDF "undefined reference to `ogdf::Initialization::Initialization()'"

Tags: c++, ogdf

I am trying to get [OGDF](http://www.ogdf.net/doku.php) working to see if it is suitable for my project, but I am having trouble with a sample program.

I am trying to compile [this example program](http://www.ogdf.net/doku.php/tech%3ahowto%3agenacyrangr):

```
#include <ogdf/basic/Graph.h>
#include <ogdf/basic/graph_generators.h>
#include <ogdf/layered/DfsAcyclicSubgraph.h>

using namespace ogdf;

int main()
{
    Graph G;
    randomSimpleGraph(G, 10, 20);
    DfsAcyclicSubgraph DAS;
    DAS.callAndReverse(G);
    G.writeGML("test.gml");

    return 0;
}
```

using this command:

```
$g++ -pthread -I ./OGDF/ -L ./OGDF/_release/ -lOGDF test2.cpp
```

But I get the following error

```
/tmp/ccbpkfdt.o: In function `main':
test2.cpp:(.text+0x12): undefined reference to `ogdf::Graph::Graph()'
test2.cpp:(.text+0x2e): undefined reference to `ogdf::randomSimpleGraph(ogdf::Graph&, int, int)'
test2.cpp:(.text+0x4e): undefined reference to `ogdf::AcyclicSubgraphModule::callAndReverse(ogdf::Graph&)'
test2.cpp:(.text+0x62): undefined reference to `ogdf::Graph::writeGML(char const*) const'
test2.cpp:(.text+0x7f): undefined reference to `ogdf::Graph::~Graph()'
test2.cpp:(.text+0xa1): undefined reference to `ogdf::Graph::~Graph()'
/tmp/ccbpkfdt.o: In function `__static_initialization_and_destruction_0(int, int)':
test2.cpp:(.text+0xfb): undefined reference to `ogdf::Initialization::Initialization()'
test2.cpp:(.text+0x112): undefined reference to `ogdf::Initialization::~Initialization()'
/tmp/ccbpkfdt.o: In function `ogdf::DfsAcyclicSubgraph::DfsAcyclicSubgraph()':
test2.cpp:(.text._ZN4ogdf18DfsAcyclicSubgraphC2Ev[_ZN4ogdf18DfsAcyclicSubgraphC5Ev]+0x16): undefined reference to `vtable for ogdf::DfsAcyclicSubgraph'
/tmp/ccbpkfdt.o: In function `ogdf::DfsAcyclicSubgraph::~DfsAcyclicSubgraph()':
test2.cpp:(.text._ZN4ogdf18DfsAcyclicSubgraphD2Ev[_ZN4ogdf18DfsAcyclicSubgraphD5Ev]+0xb): undefined reference to `vtable for ogdf::DfsAcyclicSubgraph'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

I tried compiling hello world, with an include from OGDF, and I still got:

```
undefined reference to `ogdf::Initialization::Initialization()'
```

I think I am not linking properly or something?

Comment: I added a solution. Try it out :)

Answer (score 2):

You have to be very careful in which order you type stuff when linking with a library. 
Try putting `test2.cpp` before `-lOGDF` instead, like this:

```
g++ -pthread -I ./OGDF/ -L ./OGDF/_release/ test2.cpp -lOGDF
```

Answer (score 0):

You must build your program using the -DOGDF_DLL when using OGDF as a shared library.

See here: [http://www.ogdf.net/doku.php/tech:defines](http://www.ogdf.net/doku.php/tech%3adefines)